# Do an action after Sidekiq jobs are completed without Sidekiq pro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Here is my problem.

I have a 'Job' model which has many 'transactions'.

I have a Transaction processor worker, which takes ID of the transaction and proceeds to process all the transactions of this job.

Eg:

```
job.transactions.each do |transaction|
   TransactionWorker.perform_async(transaction.id)
end
```

My requirement is that, I should intimate the user who created this job with an email, after all the transactions are complete. The transaction model has a field called 'status' which is updated in the worker itself, when it is complete.

```
 transactions.status = "complete"
 transaction.save
```

The problem is that since Sidekiq is threaded, multiple threads are processing transactions at once. I am checking for

```
  job.transactions.to_be_processed.count == 0
```

for sending the mail. Since it is threaded, I have been receiving more than 1 mail per job.

Questions:

What should be done to make this error proof, without using sidekiq pro?
I thought of moving the job completion check to after_update callback of transaction model. Will that work?